# NHibernate - use Session.Flush() in Dispose() method - good idea or not?

Tags: nhibernate, transactions, castle-windsor, unit-of-work

I use NHibernate in my application through a set of interfaces. The `ISession` is wrapped up in an interface called `IUnitOfWork` whose concrete implementation looks like this:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IUnitOfWork
{
  private ISession _session;

  public UnitOfWork()
  {
    _session = KctcSessionFactory.OpenSession();
  }

  public void Dispose()
  {
    try
    {
      _session.BeginTransaction();
      _session.Flush();
      _session.Transaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
      _session.Transaction.Rollback();
      _session.Transaction.Dispose();
      throw;
    }
  }

  public T Load<T>(int id)
  {
    return _session.Load<T>(id);
  }

  public IQueryable<T> GetList<T>()
  {
    return _session.Linq<T>();
  }

  public void Save(object entity)
  {
    _session.SaveOrUpdate(entity);
  }

  public void Delete(object entity)
  {
    _session.Delete(entity);
  }
}
```

The `IUnitOfWork` is handled by castle windsor, and has a lifestyle of `PerWebRequest`. This means that the `IUnitOfWork` is effectively a singleton from the point of view of a web request, and is disposed automatically at the end of the request.

This code looks totally foolproof to me. Any saved entities will be flushed when the `IUnitOfWork` is disposed at the end of the web request, and the whole operation is wrapped in a transaction so it's done atomically. I shouldn't ever need to use transactions outside this class. Am I right? Is this code safe? Or have I missed something horrible?

**Edited for clarity:** I want to know if I am correct in assuming that all flushing/committing to the database will wait until the session is disposed, and therefore can be wrapped in a single transaction in the `Dispose` method. Or are there situations where data may be flushed before I do it explicitly in the `Dispose` method? Or where I might need to explicitly use transactions for some other reason?

Comment: Whoops! I just realised I don't need _session.Flush() when I can just commit the transaction. This isn't production code btw.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see several problems with the way you are using NHibernate.

1) If you are using NHibernate with default settings, it is running with flush mode AUTO, which means that changes will sometimes be flushed to the db when you execute a query in order to avoid stale results. This could mean that stuff would be flushed prematurely, outside of your transaction.

2) When your transaction only spans the flush operation, reads occur outside of the transaction and are not subject to the same isolation level as the transaction. For the transaction to be truly atomic and isolated, you need to start a transaction *immediately* after creating the session.

A better uow would be something like this:

```
public class UnitOfWork : IDisposable
{
    ISession currentSession;
    bool shouldCommit;

    public UnitOfWork()
    {
        currentSession = KctcSessionFactory.OpenSession();
        currentSession.BeginTransaction();
    }

    public void Commit()
    {
        shouldCommit = true;
    }

    public void Dispose()
    {
        if (shouldCommit)
        {
            currentSession.Transaction.Commit();
        }
        else
        {
            currentSession.Transaction.Rollback();
        }

        currentSession.Dispose();
    }
}
```

allowing usage scenarios where someone would need to somehow check if the web request succeeded with no exceptions, calling `Commit` on the current uow if that was the case.

Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you. That's a big help. Ensuring that exceptions prevent comitting the UOW shouldn't be particularly difficult. The IOC container, and therefore the UOW, would be visible to any exception handling code.

Comment: But you have reminded me that it may not actually be desirable to leave flushing the ISession to the DB this late. For example, I may need to know if the flush succeeded before doing something else, for example, sending a confirmation email. I have plenty to think about here.

Comment: Generally, I would suggest decoupling integration with external systems (like e.g. sending mails) behind some kind of messaging infrastructure. If you use MSMQ for that, e.g. by using NServiceBus, you can get messaging and db operations to participate in the same transaction, thus allowing a `SendMail` message delivery transaction to be rolled back along with the database transaction.

Answer (score 2):

Committing the transaction will automatically flush the session, so no you don't need to. I wouldn't put Load and GetList methods in a unit of work, since that's more of a concern for a Repository or DAO. Otherwise it looks fine to me.

Comment: Thanks. Re: Load and GetList. All my data access is done through reposoitories, but the repositories in turn call the IUnitOfWork's methods. That's because in NHibernate, this functionality is accessed through the ISession, as you can see in the code.

Comment: @David, yes I understand your design. What I'm saying is that it's not optimal. I would follow the principal of separation of concerns. The Unit of work should be responsible for starting a transaction, and committing and disposing the session, when complete. Your repository should be concerned with CRUD. There is nothing stopping you from injecting both with an NHibernate Session and using them for different things. You just need to make sure to configure your IOC container to inject both of them with the same instance of the Session.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you for your clarification. I guess you have a much sharper idea in your mind than I do regarding what a unit of work's responsibilities should be. My concept of what a unit of work does pretty much comes from the idea that the ISession is itself a unit of work implementation. It never struck me that the ISession itself had broader responsibilities.

Comment: @David, I hadn't noticed that you're actually starting a transaction just to flush. @mookid8000 had a good implementation for the Unit of work. A unit of work manages your session, while the repository does crud interaction. You don't need to wrap your crud interaction in yet another layer.